# Is it technically possible, and does it even make sense to use Dart with Lift?

Tags: lift, dart

I like what I read about **[Lift](http://liftweb.net/)**, and I like the concept of **[Dart](http://www.dartlang.org/)**, but have little experience in both to be able to decide if thinking about using them in the same project is even making sense.

I want both writing structured client side code, and not having to worry about the [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project) as much

Can they work together? Does it make sense at all? Did anyone try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have integrated Dart with Lift using REST services together with Dart's [XmlHTTPRequest](http://api.dartlang.org/html/XMLHttpRequest.html) and liked the result. I would say that any web framework that makes making RESTful services as easy as Lift does is a perfect match for Dart. On the other hand web frameworks such as JSF which requires components to take part of a advanced life cycle are probably not a good fit.

That being said, having the same language on the client and the server side is definitely a win, so when the Dart VM matures a bit more and starts to include RESTful functionality similar to what [Express](http://expressjs.com/) does for [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org/) then I would probably use that instead.

Already now [baby steps](http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/samples/chat/README) are being taken for including HTTP support in Dart semilar to what Node provides on V8. Another important point for Dart is that it allows the browser and server to share rich objects, like what GWT does for Java, and this should further ease building advanced web applications with Dart.